# Maven assembly plugin: filter not escaping backslash when colons exist

Tags: maven-assembly-plugin

I'm filtering some configuration files with the Maven assembly plugin 2.4 and have got the problem that in .bat files, literal backslashes are not escaped when the value contains a colon.

pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
  <configuration>
    <filters>
      <filter>src/assembly/filter.properties</filter>
    </filters>
    <descriptors>
      <descriptor>src/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
    </descriptors>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

filter.properties:

```
#Double (escaped) backslashes
testPath1 = a\\b\\c
testPath2 = c:\\test
#testPath3 contains no colon
testPath3 = c\\test
```

test.bat:

```
REM ${testPath1}
REM ${testPath2}
REM ${testPath3}
```

test.properties:

```
path1=${testPath1}
path2=${testPath2}
path3=${testPath3}
```

assembly.xml:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
  <id>distribution</id>
  <formats><format>zip</format></formats>
  <files>
    <file>
      <source>${basedir}/src/assembly/testBat.bat</source>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
      <filtered>true</filtered>
    </file>
    <file>
      <source>${basedir}/src/assembly/testProp.properties</source>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
      <filtered>true</filtered>
    </file>
  </files>
</assembly>
```

And this produces...

testBat.bat (all backslashes were escaped):

```
REM a\b\c
REM c:\test\path
REM c\test\path
```

testProp.properties (backslashes in path2 are not escaped as expected!!!):

```
path1=a\b\c
path2=c:\\test\\path
path3=c\test\path
```

Anyone know if this is some kind of special feature, or actually a bug? :)

Answer (score 0):

Just as an update, I'm now using Ant's filterset functionality instead of the Maven assembly plugin's filtering. Originally I wanted to create the environment-specific artifacts with Maven, but then, due to having numerous slightly different environments, decided to build just one delivery package with Maven, and then have Ant scripts fill the configuration templates at deploy-time.